# Javascript/jQuery sortable array data into selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JSON data and set into html select box. It's working OK but the result data show is not sortable correctly.

As you can see on Snippet demo, It's show : Line 1, Line 11, Line 13, Line 2.

What I want is: Line 1, Line 3, Line 11, Line 13.

```js
var objs = [ 
    { lineName: 'LINE 1', lineID: 'LI01' },
    { lineName: 'LINE 2', lineID: 'LI02' },
    { lineName: 'LINE 11', lineID: 'LI04' },
    { lineName: 'LINE 13', lineID: 'LI05' }
];

const sorter2 = (sortBy) => (a, b) => a[sortBy].toLowerCase() > b[sortBy].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;

objs.sort(sorter2('lineName'));
console.log("Using sorter2 - passed param sortBy='lineName'", objs);

for(var i=0; i<objs.length; i++) {
  var lineID = objs[i].lineID;
  var lineName = objs[i].lineName;

  $("#line").append("<option value='" + lineID + "'>" + lineName + "</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="line">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var objs = [ 
    { lineName: 'LINE 1', lineID: 'LI01' },
    { lineName: 'LINE 2', lineID: 'LI02' },
    { lineName: 'LINE 11', lineID: 'LI04' },
    { lineName: 'LINE 13', lineID: 'LI05' }
];

//const sorter2 = (sortBy) => (a, b) => a[sortBy].toLowerCase() > b[sortBy].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
const sorter2 = _.sortBy(objs,'lineName');
//objs.sort(sorter2('lineName'));
console.log("Using sorter2 - passed param sortBy='lineName'", objs);

for(var i=0; i<objs.length; i++) {
  var lineID = objs[i].lineID;
  var lineName = objs[i].lineName;

  $("#line").append("<option value='" + lineID + "'>" + lineName + "</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<select id="line">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

using lodash you can easily achive your goal